# unable to set cell value in excel on basis of column number only

Tags: java, excel, selenium, selenium-webdriver, apache-poi

i have created a excel reader file. i am able to set cell value on basis of sheetName,colName,rowNum and data but me **unable to create a method that will set cell value on basis of sheetname,colno, rowno and data**. So how to create a method using  the above parameter and set the cell values. get cell data method and set cell data both the methods are working without any errror.

```
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Calendar;

import org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFCellStyle;
import org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFDateUtil;
import org.apache.poi.hssf.util.HSSFColor;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Cell;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.CellStyle;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.IndexedColors;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFCell;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFCellStyle;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFCreationHelper;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFFont;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFHyperlink;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFRow;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFSheet;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook;


public class ExcelReader {

    public  String path;
    public  FileInputStream fis = null;
    public  FileOutputStream fileOut =null;
    private XSSFWorkbook workbook = null;
    private XSSFSheet sheet = null;
    private XSSFRow row   =null;
    private XSSFCell cell = null;

    public ExcelReader(String path) {

        this.path=path;
        try {
            fis = new FileInputStream(path);
            workbook = new XSSFWorkbook(fis);
            sheet = workbook.getSheetAt(0);
            fis.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {

            e.printStackTrace();
        } 

    }


    // returns the row count in a sheet
    public int getRowCount(String sheetName){
        int index = workbook.getSheetIndex(sheetName);
        if(index==-1)
            return 0;
        else{
        sheet = workbook.getSheetAt(index);
        int number=sheet.getLastRowNum()+1;
        return number;
        }

    }



    // returns the data from a cell
    public String getCellData(String sheetName,String colName,int rowNum){
        try{
            if(rowNum <=0)
                return "";

        int index = workbook.getSheetIndex(sheetName);
        int col_Num=-1;
        if(index==-1)
            return "";

        sheet = workbook.getSheetAt(index);
        row=sheet.getRow(0);
        for(int i=0;i<row.getLastCellNum();i++){
            //System.out.println(row.getCell(i).getStringCellValue().trim());
            if(row.getCell(i).getStringCellValue().trim().equals(colName.trim()))
                col_Num=i;
        }
        if(col_Num==-1)
            return "";

        sheet = workbook.getSheetAt(index);
        row = sheet.getRow(rowNum-1);
        if(row==null)
            return "";
        cell = row.getCell(col_Num);

        if(cell==null)
            return "";

        if(cell.getCellType()==Cell.CELL_TYPE_STRING)
              return cell.getStringCellValue();
        else if(cell.getCellType()==Cell.CELL_TYPE_NUMERIC || cell.getCellType()==Cell.CELL_TYPE_FORMULA ){

              String cellText  = String.valueOf(cell.getNumericCellValue());
              if (HSSFDateUtil.isCellDateFormatted(cell)) {

                  double d = cell.getNumericCellValue();

                  Calendar cal =Calendar.getInstance();
                  cal.setTime(HSSFDateUtil.getJavaDate(d));
                    cellText =
                     (String.valueOf(cal.get(Calendar.YEAR))).substring(2);
                   cellText = cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH) + "/" +
                              cal.get(Calendar.MONTH)+1 + "/" + 
                              cellText;



                 }



              return cellText;
          }else if(cell.getCellType()==Cell.CELL_TYPE_BLANK)
              return ""; 
          else 
              return String.valueOf(cell.getBooleanCellValue());

        }
        catch(Exception e){

            e.printStackTrace();
            return "row "+rowNum+" or column "+colName +" does not exist in xls";
        }
    }



    // returns the data from a cell
    public String getCellData(String sheetName,int colNum,int rowNum){
        try{
            if(rowNum <=0)
                return "";

        int index = workbook.getSheetIndex(sheetName);

        if(index==-1)
            return "";


        sheet = workbook.getSheetAt(index);
        row = sheet.getRow(rowNum-1);
        if(row==null)
            return "";
        cell = row.getCell(colNum);
        if(cell==null)
            return "";

      if(cell.getCellType()==Cell.CELL_TYPE_STRING)
          return cell.getStringCellValue();
      else if(cell.getCellType()==Cell.CELL_TYPE_NUMERIC || cell.getCellType()==Cell.CELL_TYPE_FORMULA ){

          String cellText  = String.valueOf(cell.getNumericCellValue());
          if (HSSFDateUtil.isCellDateFormatted(cell)) {
               // format in form of M/D/YY
              double d = cell.getNumericCellValue();

              Calendar cal =Calendar.getInstance();
              cal.setTime(HSSFDateUtil.getJavaDate(d));
                cellText =
                 (String.valueOf(cal.get(Calendar.YEAR))).substring(2);
               cellText = cal.get(Calendar.MONTH)+1 + "/" +
                          cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH) + "/" +
                          cellText;



             }



          return cellText;
      }else if(cell.getCellType()==Cell.CELL_TYPE_BLANK)
          return "";
      else 
          return String.valueOf(cell.getBooleanCellValue());
        }
        catch(Exception e){

            e.printStackTrace();
            return "row "+rowNum+" or column "+colNum +" does not exist  in xls";
        }
    }




    // returns true if data is set successfully else false
    public boolean setCellData(String sheetName,String colName,int rowNum, String data){
        try{
        fis = new FileInputStream(path); 
        workbook = new XSSFWorkbook(fis);

        if(rowNum<=0)
            return false;

        int index = workbook.getSheetIndex(sheetName);
        int colNum=-1;
        if(index==-1)
            return false;


        sheet = workbook.getSheetAt(index);


        row=sheet.getRow(0);
        for(int i=0;i<row.getLastCellNum();i++){
            //System.out.println(row.getCell(i).getStringCellValue().trim());
            if(row.getCell(i).getStringCellValue().trim().equals(colName))
                colNum=i;
        }
        if(colNum==-1)
            return false;

        sheet.autoSizeColumn(colNum); 
        row = sheet.getRow(rowNum-1);
        if (row == null)
            row = sheet.createRow(rowNum-1);

        cell = row.getCell(colNum); 
        if (cell == null)
            cell = row.createCell(colNum);


        cell.setCellValue(data);

        fileOut = new FileOutputStream(path);

        workbook.write(fileOut);

        fileOut.close();    

        }
        catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }



    // returns true if data is set successfully else false
    public boolean setCellData(String sheetName,String colName,int rowNum, String data,String url){

        try{
        fis = new FileInputStream(path); 
        workbook = new XSSFWorkbook(fis);

        if(rowNum<=0)
            return false;

        int index = workbook.getSheetIndex(sheetName);
        int colNum=-1;
        if(index==-1)
            return false;


        sheet = workbook.getSheetAt(index);

        row=sheet.getRow(0);
        for(int i=0;i<row.getLastCellNum();i++){

            if(row.getCell(i).getStringCellValue().trim().equalsIgnoreCase(colName))
                colNum=i;
        }

        if(colNum==-1)
            return false;
        sheet.autoSizeColumn(colNum); 
        row = sheet.getRow(rowNum-1);
        if (row == null)
            row = sheet.createRow(rowNum-1);

        cell = row.getCell(colNum); 
        if (cell == null)
            cell = row.createCell(colNum);

        cell.setCellValue(data);
        XSSFCreationHelper createHelper = workbook.getCreationHelper();

        //cell style for hyperlinks

        CellStyle hlink_style = workbook.createCellStyle();
        XSSFFont hlink_font = workbook.createFont();
        hlink_font.setUnderline(XSSFFont.U_SINGLE);
        hlink_font.setColor(IndexedColors.BLUE.getIndex());
        hlink_style.setFont(hlink_font);
        //hlink_style.setWrapText(true);

        XSSFHyperlink link = createHelper.createHyperlink(XSSFHyperlink.LINK_FILE);
        link.setAddress(url);
        cell.setHyperlink(link);
        cell.setCellStyle(hlink_style);

        fileOut = new FileOutputStream(path);
        workbook.write(fileOut);

        fileOut.close();    

        }
        catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }



    // returns true if sheet is created successfully else false
    public boolean addSheet(String  sheetname){     

        FileOutputStream fileOut;
        try {
             workbook.createSheet(sheetname);   
             fileOut = new FileOutputStream(path);
             workbook.write(fileOut);
             fileOut.close();           
        } catch (Exception e) {         
            e.printStackTrace();
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }

    // returns true if sheet is removed successfully else false if sheet does not exist
    public boolean removeSheet(String sheetName){       
        int index = workbook.getSheetIndex(sheetName);
        if(index==-1)
            return false;

        FileOutputStream fileOut;
        try {
            workbook.removeSheetAt(index);
            fileOut = new FileOutputStream(path);
            workbook.write(fileOut);
            fileOut.close();            
        } catch (Exception e) {         
            e.printStackTrace();
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }
    // returns true if column is created successfully
    public boolean addColumn(String sheetName,String colName){


        try{                
            fis = new FileInputStream(path); 
            workbook = new XSSFWorkbook(fis);
            int index = workbook.getSheetIndex(sheetName);
            if(index==-1)
                return false;

        XSSFCellStyle style = workbook.createCellStyle();
        style.setFillForegroundColor(HSSFColor.GREY_40_PERCENT.index);
        style.setFillPattern(HSSFCellStyle.SOLID_FOREGROUND);

        sheet=workbook.getSheetAt(index);

        row = sheet.getRow(0);
        if (row == null)
            row = sheet.createRow(0);


        if(row.getLastCellNum() == -1)
            cell = row.createCell(0);
        else
            cell = row.createCell(row.getLastCellNum());

            cell.setCellValue(colName);
            cell.setCellStyle(style);

            fileOut = new FileOutputStream(path);
            workbook.write(fileOut);
            fileOut.close();            

        }catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
            return false;
        }

        return true;


    }



    // removes a column and all the contents
    public boolean removeColumn(String sheetName, int colNum) {
        try{
        if(!isSheetExist(sheetName))
            return false;
        fis = new FileInputStream(path); 
        workbook = new XSSFWorkbook(fis);
        sheet=workbook.getSheet(sheetName);
        XSSFCellStyle style = workbook.createCellStyle();
        style.setFillForegroundColor(HSSFColor.GREY_40_PERCENT.index);
        XSSFCreationHelper createHelper = workbook.getCreationHelper();
        style.setFillPattern(HSSFCellStyle.NO_FILL);



        for(int i =0;i<getRowCount(sheetName);i++){
            row=sheet.getRow(i);    
            if(row!=null){
                cell=row.getCell(colNum);
                if(cell!=null){
                    cell.setCellStyle(style);
                    row.removeCell(cell);
                }
            }
        }
        fileOut = new FileOutputStream(path);
        workbook.write(fileOut);
        fileOut.close();
        }
        catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
            return false;
        }
        return true;

    }


  // find whether sheets exists 
    public boolean isSheetExist(String sheetName){
        int index = workbook.getSheetIndex(sheetName);
        if(index==-1){
            index=workbook.getSheetIndex(sheetName.toUpperCase());
                if(index==-1)
                    return false;
                else
                    return true;
        }
        else
            return true;
    }


    // returns number of columns in a sheet 
    public int getColumnCount(String sheetName){
        // check if sheet exists
        if(!isSheetExist(sheetName))
         return -1;

        sheet = workbook.getSheet(sheetName);
        row = sheet.getRow(0);

        if(row==null)
            return -1;

        return row.getLastCellNum();



    }


    //String sheetName, String testCaseName,String keyword ,String URL,String message
    public boolean addHyperLink(String sheetName,String screenShotColName,String testCaseName,int index,String url,String message){


        url=url.replace('\\', '/');
        if(!isSheetExist(sheetName))
             return false;

        sheet = workbook.getSheet(sheetName);

        for(int i=2;i<=getRowCount(sheetName);i++){
            if(getCellData(sheetName, 0, i).equalsIgnoreCase(testCaseName)){

                setCellData(sheetName, screenShotColName, i+index, message,url);
                break;
            }
        }


        return true; 
    }
    public int getCellRowNum(String sheetName,String colName,String cellValue){

        for(int i=2;i<=getRowCount(sheetName);i++){
            if(getCellData(sheetName,colName , i).equalsIgnoreCase(cellValue)){
                return i;
            }
        }
        return -1;

    }


    // to run this on stand alone
    public static void main(String arg[]) throws IOException{


        ExcelReader datatable = null;


             datatable = new ExcelReader("C:\\CM3.0\\app\\test\\Framework\\AutomationBvt\\src\\config\\xlfiles\\Controller.xlsx");
                for(int col=0 ;col< datatable.getColumnCount("TC5"); col++){
                    System.out.println(datatable.getCellData("TC5", col, 1));
                }
    }


}
```

Comment: try to make your question more clearly.

Answer (score 0):

```
    row=sheet.getRow(0);
    for(int i=0;i<row.getLastCellNum();i++){

        if(row.getCell(i).getStringCellValue().trim().equalsIgnoreCase(colName))
            colNum=i;
    }
```

This block of code will not return a column number. To get column number from column name, use:

```
colNum = CellReference.convertColStringToIndex(colName);
```

If colname is "A", it returns 0, if colname is "B", it returns 1 and so forth.

Also, this code will not set the column to autofit:

```
sheet.autoSizeColumn(colNum); 
....
cell.setCellValue(data);
```

You need to reverse the order:

```
cell.setCellValue(data);
sheet.autoSizeColumn(colNum);
```

Comment: instead of this method  setCellData(String sheetName,String colName,int rowNum, String data)  i want to create a method   setCellData(String sheetName,int colNum,int rowNum, String data)

Comment: i dont want to pass column name in argument. just sheetname,rownnum ,colNum and data

Answer (score 0):

If you're asking for a `setCellValue(...)` method that requires the following `Workbook workbook, String sheetName, int rowNum, int colNum, String value` as parameters, here it is (with the personal touch of using [IllegalArgumentException](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/IllegalArgumentException.html)):

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws EncryptedDocumentException, IOException {
    
    String excelFilePath = "D:\\Desktop\\testExcel.xlsx";
    Workbook workbook = WorkbookFactory.create(new FileInputStream(excelFilePath));
    
    setCellValue(workbook,"Sheet1", 1, 1, "new string value");
    
    FileOutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream(excelFilePath);
    workbook.write(outputStream);
    workbook.close();
    outputStream.close();
            
}

public static void setCellValue(Workbook workbook, String sheetName, int rowNum, int colNum, String value) throws IllegalArgumentException {
    
    if (rowNum <= 0 || colNum <= 0) throw new IllegalArgumentException("Both \"rowNum\" and \"colNum\" must be greater then zero.");
    --rowNum;
    --colNum;
    Sheet sheet = workbook.getSheet(sheetName);
    if (sheet == null) throw new IllegalArgumentException("There is no sheet called \"" + sheetName + "\".");
    Row row = sheet.getRow(rowNum);
    if (row == null) row = sheet.createRow(rowNum);
    Cell cell = row.getCell(colNum);
    if (cell != null) {
        if (cell.getCellType() != CellType.STRING && cell.getCellType() != CellType.BLANK) 
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Cannot set String value in a Cell whose type is \"" + cell.getCellType() + "\".");
    } else {
        cell = row.createCell(rowNum);
    }
    cell.setCellValue(value);
}
```

Note that both [Sheet#getRow(int rownum)](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/dev/org/apache/poi/ss/usermodel/Sheet.html#getRow-int-) and [Row#getCell(int cellnum)](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/dev/org/apache/poi/ss/usermodel/Row.html#getCell-int-) require *zero-based indexes* as parameters so if you want your method to accept the effective row or column number (as first, second, ecc...) you must subtract one (as shown above).